# Android - moving char array value to same char array

Tags: android, arrays, eclipse, porter-stemmer

how am I going to move the value of a char array to the same char array? Here's a code:

Assuming ctr_r1=1 ,

```
for(int ctr_x = (ctr_r1 + 2) ; ctr_x < letters.length - 2 ; ctr_x++)
 {
  letters[ctr_x] = letters[ctr_x];
 }

sb.append(letters);
char[] lettersr1 = sb.toString().toCharArray();
sb1.append(lettersr1);
```

append the "letters", then convert it to string, then convert it to char array then make it as "lettersr1" value.

what im trying to accomplish is given the word EUCHARIST, i need to take the word HARIST out and place it on another array and call it region 1 (Porter2 stemming algorithm).

The code "ctr_X = (ctr_r1 + 2)" starts with H until T. The problem is I cannot pass the value directly that's why i'm trying to update the existing char array then append it.

I tried doing this:

```
char[] lettersr1 = null;
for(int ctr_x = (ctr_r1 + 2) ; ctr_x < letters.length - 2 ; ctr_x++)
 {
   lettersr1[ctr_x] = letters[ctr_x];
 }

sb.append(lettersr1);
```

but my app crashes when i do that. Any help please. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand what you're trying to do, but I can comment on your code:

```
letters[ctr_x] = letters[ctr_x];
```

This is a noop: it sets an array element value to the value it already has.

```
char[] lettersr1 = null;
for(int ctr_x = (ctr_r1 + 2) ; ctr_x < letters.length - 2 ; ctr_x++) {
    lettersr1[ctr_x] = letters[ctr_x];
```

This obviously causes a NullPointerException, since you're trying to access an array which is null. You must initialize the array before being able to modify it:

```
char[] lettersr1 = new char[someLength];
```

Additional note: you should choose better names for your variables. The names should tell what the variable represents, and they should respect the Java naming conventions (no underscores in variable names, camelCase). `ctr_x`, `ctr_r1` and `lettersr1` don't mean anything.

EDIT:

I'm still not sure what you want to do, and why you don't simply use `substring()`, but here's how to transform EUCHARIST to HARIST:

```
    char[] eucharist = "EUCHARIST".toCharArray();
    char[] harist = new char[6];
    System.arraycopy(eucharist, 3, harist, 0, 6);
    String haristAsString = new String(harist);
    System.out.println(haristAsString);

    // or

    char[] harist2 = new char[6];
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        harist2[i] = eucharist[i + 3];
    }
    String harist2AsString = new String(harist2);
    System.out.println(harist2AsString);

    // or

    String harist3AsString = "EUCHARIST".substring(3);
    char[] harist3 = harist3AsString.toCharArray();
    System.out.println(harist3AsString);
```

Comment: Arrays have a fixes size. If you want to transform an array of 9 chars to an array of 6 chars, you need to create a new array of 6 chars ans copy the 6 chars from the first array to the second array. Or simply use substring() on the first string to get you a second string containing the 6 chars you want.

Comment: What im trying to do is:

    1. place my sample word EUCHARIST to letters[] character array.

    2. take HARIST out and place it inside letters[] array again so

    EUCHARIST array becomes HARIST.

    3. append ( sb.append(letters) )the updated letters[] array so i 

    can convert it to string, then finally, convert it to char array 

    so I can do number 4.

    4. char[] lettersr1 = sb.toString().toCharArray();

    5. Display the value of lettersr1

Comment: that's it! that's what I need to do. transfer my 9 character array (EUCHARIST) to HARIST but I get error when I transfer it.

sorry if i cannot explain clearly. Im doing my best believe me.
Thank you for the add.note. Im gonna fix my variable namings. :)

Comment: Still not so clear. See my edits. Also: you don't have "error". Your have a specific error, coming with a message and a stack trace, which indicates what the problem is and where it comes from. Read this error message.

Comment: Hi! I just read your edit. I apologize for not being able to explain clearly. But I got my answer now. Following your examples, I transformed my 15 line code to 5 lines! thanks a lot! I never knew there was a substring, arraycopy, etc. Thanks a lot JB! :)

Answer (score 1):

May be so:

```
String str = "EUCHARIST";
str = str.substring(3);
```

and after toCharArray() or smth another

Comment: ill try to work around this substring. Thank you for the response. :)